# Application session in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, session, authentication

I need to create a "login application" but I don't know about session in iOS. My application need login to my website (PHP based website) to get data. Can anybody tell me how to create and manage application session in iOS app? Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is your definition of an 'application session' and what do you want to store in it?

Comment: Sorry :(... I want to create an application login to my website (PHP based website) to get data. I dont known a lot about session in iPhone. Help me Plz :D

Comment: Can you tell me how do I create a web/server session by accessing the web server from ios? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no concept of web/browser session (whatever that means to you) in iOS. iOS applications are just launched when a user touches the icon, and are quit when the user quit them.

Typically you require the user to input the login id and the password when the app is launched, and you create a web/server/browser session by accessing the web server. You can keep the id and the password securely inside in the storage of the iPhone, so that the user doesn't need to input them again and again whenever the program is launched.

Comment: Sorry, but I need some extra information, After sending the login request from iphone to my webapplication, I think here a session is created in my webapp (right?), what about my next request? can I access the same session created for the first request.. In another word : can I share data in the web session (in the server) to be accessible in each request sent by ios application after login.

Comment: @Saeed you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: No Concept of session in iOS...is this still accurate with Xcode 13, Swift 5, & iOS 15/16?